# How to interpolate a cube using fromRotationTranslationScaleOrigin in gl-matrix?

Tags: animation, glsl, webgl, interpolation, gl-matrix

Code: https://plnkr.co/edit/QNA31hMYnIJwotwbaDhT?p=preview

Question: How can I interpolate all properties of [fromRotationTranslationScaleOrigin from gl-matrix](http://glmatrix.net/docs/mat4.js.html#line1139)in draw function of this cube?

Let's interpolate over 3 seconds:
**from:**

```
q = quat.create(),
translate =[-3, 0, -10],
scale = [1,1,1],
pivot = [0,0,0]
```

**to:**

```
q = quat.create(),
translate =[0, 0, -8],
scale = [3,3,3],
pivot = [1,1,1]
```

**Program:**

```js
var gl,
    shaderProgram,
    vertices,
    matrix = mat4.create(),
    vertexCount,
    indexCount,
    q = quat.create(),
    translate =[-3, 0, -10],
    scale = [1,1,1],
    pivot = [0,0,0];


initGL();
createShaders();
createVertices();
createIndices();
draw();

function initGL() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

function createShaders() {
  var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");
  var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");

  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
}

function createVertices() {
  vertices = [
    -1, -1, -1,     1, 0, 0, 1,     // 0
     1, -1, -1,     1, 1, 0, 1,     // 1
    -1,  1, -1,     0, 1, 1, 1,     // 2
     1,  1, -1,     0, 0, 1, 1,     // 3
    -1,  1,  1,     1, 0.5, 0, 1,   // 4
     1,  1,  1,     0.5, 1, 1, 1,   // 5
    -1, -1,  1,     1, 0, 0.5, 1,   // 6
     1, -1,  1,     0.5, 0, 1, 1,   // 7
  ];

  vertexCount = vertices.length / 7;

  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var coords = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coords");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(coords, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 7, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coords);  

  var colorsLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "colors");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorsLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 7, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 3);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorsLocation);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  var pointSize = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "pointSize");
  gl.vertexAttrib1f(pointSize, 20);

//   var color = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
//   gl.uniform4f(color, 0, 0, 0, 1);

  var perspectiveMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.perspective(perspectiveMatrix, 1, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 11);
  var perspectiveLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "perspectiveMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(perspectiveLoc, false, perspectiveMatrix);

}

function createIndices() {
  var indices = [
    0, 1, 2,   1, 2, 3,
    2, 3, 4,   3, 4, 5,
    4, 5, 6,   5, 6, 7,
    6, 7, 0,   7, 0, 1,
    0, 2, 6,   2, 6, 4,
    1, 3, 7,   3, 7, 5
  ];
  indexCount = indices.length;

  var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


}

function draw() {

  mat4.fromRotationTranslationScaleOrigin(
    matrix,
    q,
    translate,
    scale,
    pivot
  );

  var transformMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transformMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(transformMatrix, false, matrix);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexCount, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


  /*
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context
   */
  function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript, theSource, currentChild, shader;

    shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!shaderScript) {
      return null;
    }

    theSource = "";
    currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

    while (currentChild) {
      if (currentChild.nodeType == currentChild.TEXT_NODE) {
        theSource += currentChild.textContent;
      }

      currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
    }
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
      // Unknown shader type
      return null;
    }
    gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);

// Compile the shader program
    gl.compileShader(shader);

// See if it compiled successfully
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }

    return shader;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

  <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  attribute vec4 coords;
  attribute float pointSize;
  uniform mat4 transformMatrix;
  attribute vec4 colors;
  varying vec4 varyingColors;
  uniform mat4 perspectiveMatrix;
  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = perspectiveMatrix * transformMatrix  * coords;
    gl_PointSize = pointSize;
    varyingColors = colors;
  }
  </script>

  <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 color;
  varying vec4 varyingColors;
  void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = varyingColors;
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the call back function of [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is passe one single argument, which is a time value.
This time can be used to calculate a matrix by a function of time.

```js
function draw(timeMs) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    let interval = timeMs / 3000; // 3000 ms are 3 seconds
    let t = interval - Math.floor(interval);  

    // [...]
}
```

Use `vec3.lerp` to interpolate the translation, pivot and scale, dependent on the time interval `t`:

```js
function draw(timeMs) {

    // [...]

    let trans_t = vec3.lerp([], translate, translate2, t);
    let scale_t = vec3.lerp([], scale, scale2, t);
    let pivot_t = vec3.lerp([], pivot, pivot2, t);

    mat4.fromRotationTranslationScaleOrigin(matrix, q, trans_t, scale_t, pivot_t);

    // [...]

}
```

See the example, where I applied the suggestions to the code of the question:

```js
var gl,
    shaderProgram,
    vertices,
    matrix = mat4.create(),
    vertexCount,
    indexCount,
    q = quat.create(),
    translate =[-3, 0, -10],
    scale = [1,1,1],
    pivot = [0,0,0];
    
    translate2 = [0, 0, -8],
    scale2 = [3,3,3],
    pivot2 = [1,1,1]


initGL();
createShaders();
createVertices();
createIndices();
draw();

function initGL() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

function createShaders() {
  var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");
  var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");

  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
}

function createVertices() {
  vertices = [
    -1, -1, -1,     1, 0, 0, 1,     // 0
     1, -1, -1,     1, 1, 0, 1,     // 1
    -1,  1, -1,     0, 1, 1, 1,     // 2
     1,  1, -1,     0, 0, 1, 1,     // 3
    -1,  1,  1,     1, 0.5, 0, 1,   // 4
     1,  1,  1,     0.5, 1, 1, 1,   // 5
    -1, -1,  1,     1, 0, 0.5, 1,   // 6
     1, -1,  1,     0.5, 0, 1, 1,   // 7
  ];

  vertexCount = vertices.length / 7;

  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var coords = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coords");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(coords, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 7, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coords);  

  var colorsLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "colors");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorsLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 7, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 3);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorsLocation);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  var pointSize = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "pointSize");
  gl.vertexAttrib1f(pointSize, 20);

//   var color = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
//   gl.uniform4f(color, 0, 0, 0, 1);

  var perspectiveMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.perspective(perspectiveMatrix, 1, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 11);
  var perspectiveLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "perspectiveMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(perspectiveLoc, false, perspectiveMatrix);

}

function createIndices() {
  var indices = [
    0, 1, 2,   1, 2, 3,
    2, 3, 4,   3, 4, 5,
    4, 5, 6,   5, 6, 7,
    6, 7, 0,   7, 0, 1,
    0, 2, 6,   2, 6, 4,
    1, 3, 7,   3, 7, 5
  ];
  indexCount = indices.length;

  var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


}

function draw(timeMs) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  let interval = timeMs / 3000
  let t = interval - Math.floor(interval); 

  let trans_t = vec3.lerp([], translate, translate2, t);
  let scale_t = vec3.lerp([], scale, scale2, t);
  let pivot_t = vec3.lerp([], pivot, pivot2, t);

  mat4.fromRotationTranslationScaleOrigin(matrix, q, trans_t, scale_t, pivot_t);

  var transformMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transformMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(transformMatrix, false, matrix);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexCount, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}


  /*
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context
   */
  function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript, theSource, currentChild, shader;

    shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!shaderScript) {
      return null;
    }

    theSource = "";
    currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

    while (currentChild) {
      if (currentChild.nodeType == currentChild.TEXT_NODE) {
        theSource += currentChild.textContent;
      }

      currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
    }
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
      // Unknown shader type
      return null;
    }
    gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);

// Compile the shader program
    gl.compileShader(shader);

// See if it compiled successfully
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }

    return shader;
  }
```

```html
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 coords;
attribute float pointSize;
uniform mat4 transformMatrix;
attribute vec4 colors;
varying vec4 varyingColors;
uniform mat4 perspectiveMatrix;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = perspectiveMatrix * transformMatrix  * coords;
  gl_PointSize = pointSize;
  varyingColors = colors;
}
</script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
varying vec4 varyingColors;
void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = varyingColors;
}
</script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```